# Injecting HTML - Javascript fails with undefined on subsequent retrieval of invisible HTML

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-modal

I have a bootstrap modal with a dropdownlist that are numbered 0 - 7. The first time I choose a value, my javascript works by getting the HTML I want, and injecting it to my modal-body. All subsequent choices fail with 'undefined' when retrieving the HTML to inject.

My modal-body is as follows (For now, I have 3 different HTML's, two which are hidden. 'ParagraphAnswer' displays first when the modal is displayed. The 3 different HTMLs are a ParagraphAnswer, TrueAndFalseAnswer, and MultipleAnswer):

```
<div class="modal-body">
<div id="ParagraphAnswer">
    <div class="modalBody">
        <div class="form-group-sm">
            @Html.Label("Correct Answer", new { style = "font-weight:bold;" })
            @if (ViewData["TestQuestionError"] != null)
            {
                @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.TestsQuestions.Correct_Answer, new { @class = "form-control", style = "font-size: 1em; margin-top: -5px; width: 725px;", autofocus = "autofocus" })
            }
            else
            {
                @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.TestsQuestions.Correct_Answer, new { @class = "form-control", style = "font-size: 1em; margin-top: -5px; width: 725px;" })
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="TrueAndFalseAnswer" class="invisible">
    <div class="modalBody">
        <div class="form-group-sm">
            @Html.Label("I am a Checkbox")
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="MultipleAnswer" class="invisible">
    <div class="modalBody">
        <div class="form-group-sm">
            @Html.Label("I am a MultipleAnswer")
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The javascript is supposed to swap out the modal-body section each time I make a different selection from the dropdownlist. It works fine the first time, but subsequent choices do not retrieve the HTML the javascript asks for. I believe the problem is not the javascript, but the structure of my HTML.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Here is a portion of my javascript:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function () {
        var $modalBody = $("#Question .modal-body");

        $("#ddlQuestionType").change(function () {

        var myQuestionType = document.getElementById('ddlQuestionType').value;

        if (myQuestionType == 0) {
            var modalBodyContent = $("#MultipleAnswer .modalBody").html();
            alert(modalBodyContent);
            $modalBody.html(modalBodyContent);
        };

        if (myQuestionType == 1) {
            var modalBodyContent = $("#ParagraphAnswer .modalBody").html();
            alert(modalBodyContent);
            $modalBody.html(modalBodyContent);
        };

        if (myQuestionType == 5) {
            var modalBodyContent = $("#TrueAndFalseAnswer .modalBody").html();
            alert(modalBodyContent);
            $modalBody.html(modalBodyContent);
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: All your modal body contents are inside the modal body. The first time it can pick one of the three but then you are replacing the whole content with the selected modal body and therefore you do not have the rest of the two modal bodies anymore. you are not just showing/hiding one modal body.... you are picking one and deleting the rest of the two the first time and next time it cannot be found. You just need to make them all .hide() and then .show() the one that is desired, based on ddl selection.

Comment: That worked. Thanks!